# Do the Ra’zac have a third form?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

In *Inheritance*, the mad High Priest of Helgrind says some odd things about their gods, the Ra’zac:

> “You do not deserve such a great honor, but it will please the Old
>   Ones, and in all things we strive to satisfy their desires. We are
>   their faithful servants, and they our masters cruel and implacable:
>   the three-faced god—the hunters of men, the eaters of flesh, and the
>   drinkers of blood. To them, we offer up our bodies in hope of
>   revelation into the mysteries of this life and in hope of absolution
>   for our transgressions. As Tosk wrote, so shall it be.”
>
> <sub>*Inheritance*</sub>

While at first the bit about the three-faced god might seem to be mere “insane cultist” ravings, the first two parts actually correspond directly to the life cycle of the Ra’zac:

1. The Ra’zac, “the hunters of men,” subsist solely on humans.
2. The Lethrblaka, “the eaters of flesh,” will kill and eat anything.

   > Oromis fixed Eragon with a steady gaze. “The Ra’zac remain pupae for
   >   twenty years while they mature. On the first full moon of their
   >   twentieth year, they shed their exoskeletons, spread their wings, and
   >   emerge as adults ready to hunt all creatures, not just humans.”
   >
   > <sub>*Eldest*</sub>

Is there any confirmation that these “drinkers of blood” represent a third stage of the Ra’zac, and if so, what it might be?

Comment: [Obligatory reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHDid.jpghttps://imgflip.com/i/1n633z)

Comment: ["*Will we ever get more information on the ra’zak in future books?*" "*No comment.*"](https://www.paolini.net/stuff/articles/article-series-qas-christopher/book-5-villain-writing-character-names/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### According to Christopher: "They turn into giant butterflies and fly to the moon where they live in peace with the cannibalistic space elves."

Christopher (jokingly) answered this question on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/884872142663413761):

> **Is there a third stage for Ra'zac/Lethrblaka? The Helgrind priest seemed to imply as such with his "three-faced god" line.**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *They turn into giant butterflies and fly to the moon where they live in peace with the cannibalistic space elves. Why do you ask?*

I see three ways to interpret this:

1. Ra'zac do not have a third form, and CP doesn't understand why one would think they do.
2. Ra'zac do have a third form, and this is an elaborate form of a "no comment" response.
3. Ra'zak eventually turn into giant butterflies and fly to the moon where they live in peace with the cannibalistic space elves. (Probably related to the scifi book he's working on or something.)

Comment: This isn't quite a joke answer, but it is almost certainly a joke made by the author. Perhaps you could mention that in your answer?

Comment: I think this answer definitively says that, no, there is no third form. Maybe that should be clarified for those who might not pick up on the sarcasm.

Comment: @TBear - I could also somewhat see this as being an elaborate form of "no comment".

Comment: I agree that this is just a way of not saying anything, and I think *that* should be the header of the answer. The rest is just humor. Christopher Paolini's humor, but still.

Comment: @Adamant - I don't think he's trying to be ambiguous. A "no comment" would imply that there is a third form, while a "that question is absurd" would imply that there isn't. It seems to me that CP was going for one of those I just can't figure out which.

Comment: Either-way, this is WoG said in direct response to this specific question. If that isn't good enough then I don't know what is .

Comment: "No comment" just means that someone isn't going to say anything. A smart person often says "no comment" even when the query is wrong, either out of principle or to prevent people from guessing that their question is correct. This answer is certainly good enough, but I don't feel comfortable accepting it when the title implies that this joking answer is canon.

Comment: If you could just edit the title to better reflect what you think Christopher Paolini actually means, I could accept it. :)

Comment: @Adamant - I'm honestly not entirely sure what he means. Hence I just went with a direct quote. But I've now made some edits.